# Substrate-connect for solo-chains

Tags: polkadot-js, light-client, substrate-connect, smoldot

I don't see any support for connecting via the substract-connect library for a sovereign chain. E.g. the [`addChain` function](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-connect/blob/4399987c5f025534b9867bc7a40b7e8869a11913/projects/extension/src/content/ClientWithExtension.ts#L104) has a dependency on the relay chain.

Is there some way to connect to a custom solo chain through this library that I am not seeing? If not, is there a plan to add support?

Comment: Hi @justin-frevert, I think is possible. You can check this code used to run the zombienet tests https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-connect/blob/4399987c5f025534b9867bc7a40b7e8869a11913/.zombienet-tests/utils.js#L21C50-L21C65

Comment: AFAIK: it should work using the normal `addChain` function and then passing the chain-spec of your "sovereign chain". Did you try that already? For it to work, though, make sure that there are boot-nodes defined inside the chain-spec.

Comment: Depends on what kind of custom solo chain you are talking about. Smoldot is only capable of connecting to a solo (relay) chain like polkadot, kusame, rococo & westend.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect with a light client to any Substrate-compatible blockchai by using the `addChain` function.

To connect to that chain you need to initialize the light client and then call the `addChain` for your substrate chain (or the `addWellKnownChain` for any of the polkadot, kusama, westend and/or rococo) on this client.

Connecting to a parachain is done the same way as connecting to a standalone chain, by init-ing a client and then calling `addChain`. The difference here is that if you call `addChain` with a parachain chain specification, you **must** have connected to its corresponding relay chain beforehand (using again the same function `addChain`. Failing to do so will lead to an error at the initialization of the parachain.

For example the following would  work:

```js
// initializethe client
const client = createScClient();
// add the desired chain by providing the (stringified) chainspec
await client.addChain(relayChain);

// (optional) add the parachain (of the above added relay chain) by providing the (strinfied) chainspec of the parachain
await client.addChain(parachain);
```